# Text Watermarking on video without loss of audio and video quality

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark, video-watermarking

I am using following command to add text watermark on a video file(for mp4, mpg,m4v,flv,mov etc..):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='Opentext':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white" TextOutput.mp4
```

For some of the file transformation the property of video file changes. for example- When I tried to add text watermark on a mkv file I got this message:

> [matroska @ 0000001867d36ec0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1;
> previous:  2273, current: 1596; changing to 2273. This may result in
> incorrect timestamps in the output file.

This is one of the issues, i have mentioned here. There are others as well, such as:

- video quality is reduced
- video file size is changed(increses/decreases drastically)
- Audio lagging occurs etc...

So, I want to preserve the quality of video after adding the text watermark. How can I do that?

Comment: In `Google.com` try searching: `"mkv" Non-monotonous DTS`. Your question has been asked many times before. Research to see if the existing one-hundred answers help you.

Comment: Hi @VC.One, I was looking for a command that can help me get the watermarked output video file without any lossy transformation. The mentioned issue was just an example of issue happening.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-crf` (constant rate factor) to improve picture quality.
 Lower number is higher quality (where possible) but with slower encoding time. Test a good number.

Also use `b:v` to set a good video bit-rate (*eg:* `2500`, `3500` or `4000`).

Try:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='Opentext':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 20 -c:a copy TextOutput.mp4
```

Comment: `-b:v` and `-crf` are mutually exclusive. One of them will be ignored.

Comment: @llogan Thanks. I've removed `-b:v` since using the `-crf` might be easier logic.